# ChromeDriver: Custom Chrome Executable Path

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using the portable version of Google Chrome.

Since WebDriver expects the default installation path, it does not find the portable one which obviously is at another location:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 11.13 seconds
Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: '8df0c6b', time: '2013-08-12 15:43:19'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_05'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

How do I set a custom path to the `chrome.exe` file?

Answer (score 9):

Nevermind, I found the answer myself:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/path/to/chrome/binary");

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

[Chromedriver docs](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)

Answer (score 5):

Python version:

```
chromedriver = "/path/to/chromedriver"
options = Options()
options.binary_location = '/path/to/chrome'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, chrome_options=options)
```