# Mac + Selenium + Chrome = cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: java, macos, selenium-webdriver

Hi i m trying to setup selenium with eclipse on a Mac pc.
When I download the ChromeDriver and place it on the below folder :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/george/Downloads/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I run the code.
Then I get the following exception :

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.21.371459
>   (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4) on port 33424 Only local
>   connections are allowed. Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find
>   Chrome binary   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459
>   (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Mac OS X 10.10.5
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 312 milliseconds Build info:
>   version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
>   System info: host: 'Georges-Mac-mini.local', ip: '192.168.1.2',
>   os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.5',
>   java.version: '1.7.0_25' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

So I m assuming that some binary is missing? Note that I use regularly Chrome as my browser.. I dont know if this is related or not.
My pc is mac. I have read the ChromeDriver site but I dont understand what exactly to do. I have problems navigating to paths that are a bit strange like : "Google Drive" instead of "Google/Drive" or paths like
"cd Chrome\ Apps.localized/"  or "/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome". I mean , wt?? are those back and forth slashes ??? I just now a few things on linux but here.. i m stuck and confused
On Windows things where much easier.. you just downloaded an .exe file locally point the driver with options to that file and everything was smoothly. I cant find information on mac specific.

Can anyone help ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you download the right binary (chromedriver_mac32.zip) from here http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.21/

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978464/chromedriver-custom-chrome-executable-path

Comment: Regarding the firs comment. Thats exactly the binary I donwloaded. Regarding the second comment this is exactly where I need help because I m unaware of Mac's internal keeping of binaries and unawearness of basic navigation to Mac Apps , files etc.. that are quite different from linux. Just for the record I tried a couple of minutes ago the operadriver and worked like charm whithout any digging to binaries etc..

Comment: Also tried firefox, this one didnt even need a firefoxdriver file..

Comment: There is nothing wrong with MAC, you might have not provided right path for chrome driver. Please check whether you downloaded chrome binary for linux or for Mac

Answer (score 6):

"cannot find Chrome binary" simply means the os cannot find chrome app. Just check chrome installation directory. Right directory should be "/Applications/Google Chrome.app". If you download your chrome from third platform, the directory may be "/Applications/Chrome.app". It makes the os cannot find your chrome.

Answer (score 5):

The stack trace indicates that it cannot find the binary for the chrome webdrive.  You'll need to download it if you haven't already.  Once you have downloaded the [chrome webdriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/), point your application at the binary.

if you have a path with spaces, such as

`/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome`

you'll need to escape the spaces with backslashes like so

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome`

a backslash followed by a space, `\`, tells the argument parser not to use that space as a delimiter but rather to include it as part of the path.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from trying the path with and without slashes (the ruby driver expects spaces not be escaped), this problem may also be caused by a version mismatch between Chrome and Chromedriver.

Chrome Canary, specifically, is often unsupported by the current stable Chromedriver release. There are nightly builds linked at https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/chromedriver-canary. Enter the proper prefix in the search box for the Mac version, then scroll as far as it goes for the most recent version–yeah, the interface sucks.

There's a decent chance this won't work, either. Installing the stable Chrome release is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I found that upgrading selenium-webdriver to 3.142.3 and Capybara to 3.20.2 fixed this for me. This required making some changes to my webdriver configuration:

```rb
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
  'goog:chromeOptions': {
     args: %w(--disable-gpu --headless --no-sandbox --window-size=1024,768)
  }
)

driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, {
  browser: :chrome,
  desired_capabilities: capabilities,
  http_client: client,
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was facing this `"cannot find Chrome binary"`, when I realised that I don't have the Chrome Browser installed before to try to use it.

Don't do this at home, guys...

Answer (score -4):

Use double slashes in your path like this:

```
//Test Data//Drivers//chromedriver
```

and copy and paste the chrome driver exe to some other location.

Comment: Chrome driver exe is used in case of windows operating system and double slashes also required in windows, they are not needed in case of Mac