# Cannot find Chrome binary when executing a selenium (testng) test in jenkins on windows 7

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng

I have a basic login test with selenium and testng. When executed from eclipse, it works as expected and invoke Google Chrome. If executed from TESTNG command line, it works fine too.

This is my @Before:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() throws Exception { 
 File file = new File("C:/Selenium-driver/chromedriver.exe"); 
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath()); 
 driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
 }
```

However, if I execute the same test thru Jenkins it says:

```
Building in workspace C:\EclipsePortable\Data\workspace\GS_TESTNG 
[G_TESTNG] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson9049518275115936054.bat 

C:\EclipsePortable\Data\workspace\G_TESTNG>_test_login_cmd.bat 

C:\EclipsePortable\Data\workspace\G_TESTNG>cd C:\EclipsePortable\Data\workspace\G_TESTNG 

C:\EclipsePortable\Data\workspace\G_TESTNG>java -cp C:\EclipsePortable\Data\workspace\G_TESTNG\lib\*;C:\EclipsePortable\Data\workspace\G_TESTNG\bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml 
... 
... TestNG 6.9.9 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com) 
... 

[TestNG] Running: 
  C:\EclipsePortable\Data\workspace\G_TESTNG\testng.xml 

Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on port 36257 
Only local connections are allowed. 
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp 
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary 
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) 
Command duration or timeout: 664 milliseconds 
Build info: version: '2.51.0', revision: '1af067d', time: '2016-02-05 19:15:17' 
System info: host: 'NMTLA12810', ip: '192.168.0.179', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_102' 
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver 
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) 
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206) 
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158) 
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678) 
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249) 
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131) 
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144) 
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170) 
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159) 
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116) 
        at com.test.TestA.setUp(TestA.java:33) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) 
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85) 
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510) 
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211) 
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:585) 
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816) 
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124) 
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125) 
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108) 
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774) 
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624) 
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359) 
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354) 
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312) 
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261) 
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52) 
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86) 
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215) 
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140) 
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048) 
        at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1355) 
        at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1324) 

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass tearDown 
SKIPPED: testGooglePageTitleInChrome 

=============================================== 
    TestNG Test Group 
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1 
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1 
=============================================== 


=============================================== 
Main Test Suite 
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1 
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1 
=============================================== 

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@7fbe847c: 16 ms 
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@759ebb3d: 78 ms 
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@ba8a1dc: 59 ms 
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@1c655221: 5 ms 
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@1edf1c96: 16 ms 
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 0 ms 
Build step 'Exécuter une ligne de commande batch Windows' marked build as failure 
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ChromeDriver: Custom Chrome Executable Path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978464/chromedriver-custom-chrome-executable-path)

Answer (score 14):

I think you need to install chrome in your instance. for that you follow this basic commands

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install ./google-chrome-stable_current_*.rpm

google-chrome &
```

Comment: Yup, that's it! I had the same error until I installed Google Chrome

Comment: Haha! This was also my problem. I forgot I didn't have Chrome installed. LOL!

Comment: I was able to download the chrome but could not find the location where it is installed. That path is needed to set the CHROME_BIN variable. Any inputs?

Answer (score 6):

It is possible that chrome is installed on your AppData (especially if your are on Windows 7). I am guessing Jenkins could not access the binary from your user directory. Make sure the directory you have Chrome on, is accessible to Jenkins, or try reinstalling chrome again to program files directory.

On the other hand, you can simply instruct Chromedriver where to look for Chrome Binary,

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions= new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\ThePAthtoChrome.exe");

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: Hi Prageeth, i added otpions for chrome as you mentioned and i still get the same error. and i do not find the folder AppData.

Comment: How can i know where jenkins is looking for chrome.exe ?

Comment: I am guessing you probably configured Jenkins as a WIndows service running under Local System account. You can launch Your AppData folder by simply entering %APPDATA% in run. The AppData for Local System user account is at C:\Windows\System32\Config\systemprofile\AppData

Comment: Also, make sure the path you gave under chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\ThePAthtoChrome.exe"); is valid. It's highly unlikely that selenium would say Binary not found if you give a Valid Chrome exe path

Comment: i don't understand, should i give the path to chrome.exe or chromedriver.exe ?

Comment: i found solution with this: ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.setBinary("C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe");
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/chromedriver.exe");
   driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

Comment: Binary is for chrome not the driver.

Comment: Right, that's what I've said in the answer. Glad it helped !!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is these lines in your code:

```
File file = new File("C:/Selenium-driver/chromedriver.exe"); 
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
```

This is a massive anti-pattern that I regularly see.  The `webdriver.chrome.driver` environmental variable was designed so that you could install your chromedriver binaries on multiple systems in different places, and then set the environmental variable on each system so that if a selenium test is ever run on that system it will automatically pick up the location of the binary.

By hard coding this environmental variable via code you are ignoring any preconfigured environmental variable that was set up when the build agent was built, you are not using it in the way it was intended.

If you insist on doing it this way you should always check to see if the env variable is already set before you set it, this way you will not overwrite the existing env variable.  You will also need to make sure that the file path you have hard coded exists on your build agent (the secondary cause of your error is that it doesn't) so that if the env variable isn't set, you are actually setting a valid path to the chromedriver binary.

Answer (score 3):

I just check my chrome version (chrome://settings/help(85.0.4183.83 )) and then downloaded  chromedriver.exe accordingly (https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)and given new chrome driver.exe path...-This solves my same issue

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I was able to execute selenium scripts through local but when tried executing on Jenkins got error "unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary".

Here is my solution which worked on Jenkins server:
1. Download and enable Xvfb before start of selenium script on jenkins. For more info read here https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin
2. I am having ubuntu 16.xx os on local and jenkins server.
3. Try to keep chromedriver in "usr/bin" folder only otherwise you may get error.

```
try {

            if(service == null){
                service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                        .usingDriverExecutable(new File("/usr/bin/chromedriver"))// set the chromedriver path
                       .usingAnyFreePort()
                        .withEnvironment(ImmutableMap.of("DISPLAY", ":15"))
                        .withSilent(true)
                        .build();
                service.start();
            }

            System.out.println("Reading chrome driver");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/usr/bin/chromedriver");
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
            driver.get("https://google.com");
            driver.quit();
 }
        catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code i tried it solved my one week unresolved problem,

Thanks to Aastha Chopra..

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions= new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome Beta\\Application\\chrome.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\STUDY\\Selenium\\CHROMEDRIVERS\\chromedriver.exe");

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Mac users, Please make sure that chromeBinary file is placed at bin folder and chrome if it is in downloads move it to application.

Answer (score 0):

- Check the OS of the Agent Node.
- Check how Jenkins Access the agent Node.
  if its via JNLP and the OS is below Window 7, through Admin right install the Chrome in C:/Program Files(x86) where Jenkins can access the chrome.exe and set binaries using below code:

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
if(System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Windows Server 2012 R2")){
    File ChromeExePath =new File("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe");
    if (ChromeExePath.exists()){
        options.setBinary(ChromeExePath);
    }
}

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue in JS, it got fixed after installing `npm i chromedriver`

Answer (score 0):

Please check your binary path if still not works then

you should have installed chrome in your machine

and your chromedriver.exe version should accordingly (like if you have chrome 87.0 ver then download chromedriver.exe for ver 87.0)

download form it from
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

and given new chromedriver.exe path to your script.

This works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.BinaryLocation="C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\test3", options);

This worked for me in C#. my chromedriver.exe is in test3 folder. Also my issue was that version of chrome was not same of chromedriver. This will definitely work:)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions= new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome Beta\\Application\\chrome.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\STUDY\\Selenium\\CHROMEDRIVERS\\chromedriver.exe");

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
```

Comment: Explain what you're doing, @Aastha Chopra.

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me.  I have coded as below

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions= new ChromeOptions(); 

chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\Users\\kannanu\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",ChromeExePath);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions); 
driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
```

Comment: Please add further inofrmation about your answer. The question is very old, so an answer after some years must to give an added value

Answer (score -1):

I ran the following command to install chromedriver and it worked:

```sh
brew cask install chromedriver
```