# Getting a specific error in all browser version

Tags: javascript, selenium-chromedriver

I tried below code in different chrome versions but error not resolved.
Chrome Version 81 (32 bit)
Chrome Version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Java version 1.8
Selenium version 3.141.59

Can anyone help to resolve this.

As per code suggestion i downloaded chrome driver and changed the code mentioned below

Now i am getting different error

**Code:**

```
package sampletest;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;  
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;  
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;  
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;  

public class smaple {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe"); 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\chromedriver.exe");

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        // Instantiate a ChromeDriver class.     
   WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();  

      // Launch Website  
   driver.navigate().to("http://www.javatpoint.com/");  

    //Maximize the browser  
     driver.manage().window().maximize();  

     //Scroll down the webpage by 5000 pixels  
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;  
   js.executeScript("scrollBy(0, 5000)");   

    // Click on the Search button  
   driver.findElement(By.linkText("Core Java")).click();     

     }

    }

**Error:**

    Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185}) on port 38087
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'MUTHU-PC', ip: '192.168.42.150', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x013D0AE3+1706723]
    Ordinal0 [0x013368C1+1075393]
    Ordinal0 [0x012ADFA9+516009]
    Ordinal0 [0x0123C70E+50958]
    Ordinal0 [0x0125BFD7+180183]
    Ordinal0 [0x0125BDDD+179677]
    Ordinal0 [0x01259D4B+171339]
    Ordinal0 [0x01241D4A+73034]
    Ordinal0 [0x01242DC0+77248]
    Ordinal0 [0x01242D59+77145]
    Ordinal0 [0x0134BB37+1162039]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0146A7C6+508998]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0146A504+508292]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0147F617+594583]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0146B036+511158]
    Ordinal0 [0x01343FFC+1130492]
    Ordinal0 [0x0134D49B+1168539]
    Ordinal0 [0x0134D603+1168899]
    Ordinal0 [0x01365B05+1268485]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x769D3C45+18]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x772A37F5+239]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x772A37C8+194]

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at sampletest.smaple.main(smaple.java:18)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give the chromedriver.exe path not the path of chrome's installed location.
You need to download a chromedriver.exe which comply to your current version .
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads  Here I put it in Jar_files folder of my worksapce .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Jar_files\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        // To start Chrome in Maximized browser window
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        // To remove Chrome is being controlled by automated test software
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. I downloaded chrome driver but while trying to install i am facing error "Starting chrome driver on port 9515 . Only local connections are allowed"

Comment: Please attach the full log .

Comment: Dear Sameera De Silva, I have attached full code and full error in above code section. please refer it. In comment box i guess there is no option to attach screenshot

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144934/cannot-find-chrome-binary-when-executing-a-selenium-testng-test-in-jenkins-on/41145375

Comment: Thank alot Sameera De Silva. I gone through the link i tried the code my issue resolved after 1 week of struggle.