# unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary but it is already in the folder Jenkins in Linux Server

Tags: linux, jenkins

Previously was lower version, but i update but still fail
Any reason why? or any possible ways to try?
From my linux server whereis google-chrome it was correctly set on
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
and base on [this site](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome/chrome_finder.cc?q=chrome_finder&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=52), it stated that it will be searching for google-chrome under any one the follow
`/usr/local/sbin`
`/usr/local/bin`
`/usr/sbin`
`/usr/bin`
`/sbin`
`/bin`
`/opt/google/chrome`
which my google-chrome is also located at `/bin/google-chrome`
Also tried this [stackoverflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144934/cannot-find-chrome-binary-when-executing-a-selenium-testng-test-in-jenkins-on/41145375)
but to no avail as i tried to set the path but it just mention

```
no chrome binary at /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
```

or

```
no chrome binary at /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable/
```

Tried reinstalling chrome on my server but still the same error.

Some other information the can be provide will be

```
whereis google-chrome  
google-chrome: /usr/bin/google-chrome /usr/share/man/man1/google-chrome.1.gz  

google-chrome --version  
/bin/google-chrome: symbol lookup error: /bin/google-chrome: undefined symbol: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor
```

Current Error:

```
unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '8f5b40c32460', ip: '172.18.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_242'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

System in use

```
Google-Chrome --version
/bin/google-chrome: symbol lookup error: /bin/google-chrome: undefined symbol: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor

javac -version
javac 1.8.0_242

java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36
Installed Chrome v79
Selenium Version 3.141.59.