# Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally while running my tests using Docker

Tags: python, docker, selenium, automation, bdd

I want to create a docker image and run my tests in the container. My framework is built of Python + Behave. I am referring to this project https://github.com/William-Yeh/docker-behave but somehow my chrome driver doesn't work.

It gives me the below error. The libraries which are being installed can be found in this docker file https://github.com/William-Yeh/docker-behave/blob/master/Dockerfile I am using this file.

[image]

Comment: both the driver & browser should be updated

Comment: This link migjt help to you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144934/cannot-find-chrome-binary-when-executing-a-selenium-testng-test-in-jenkins-on/56393879#56393879

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome/issues/46#issuecomment-396783086) worked for me

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/your_chrome_driver_dir/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Even after adding these options I am getting the same error.

Comment: This worked, thanks. Previously docker image was not build correctly and hence changes were not reflected.