# Selenium isn't using my own Chrome Driver I set and is using the default one

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

So I'm trying to get the source of a webpage in Python, and for compatability reasons, I have to use Google Chrome 114 instead of the latest 116. I used a service to create it and downloaded my own version that *should* work, however it just seems to be completely ignoring it and using my system one.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_service = Service("/Users/*/Downloads/chromedriver_mac64/chromedriver") # >:(

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service)

url = "https://google.com"

driver.get(url) 


driver.implicitly_wait(10)


website_source = driver.page_source
print(website_source)

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/*/Desktop/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=chrome_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 84, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.140 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x000000010f7436b8 chromedriver + 4937400
1   chromedriver                        0x000000010f73ab73 chromedriver + 4901747
2   chromedriver                        0x000000010f2f8616 chromedriver + 435734
3   chromedriver                        0x000000010f32ad10 chromedriver + 642320
4   chromedriver                        0x000000010f32618a chromedriver + 622986
5   chromedriver                        0x000000010f32267c chromedriver + 607868
6   chromedriver                        0x000000010f369a08 chromedriver + 899592
7   chromedriver                        0x000000010f368ebf chromedriver + 896703
8   chromedriver                        0x000000010f35fde3 chromedriver + 859619
9   chromedriver                        0x000000010f32dd7f chromedriver + 654719
10  chromedriver                        0x000000010f32f0de chromedriver + 659678
11  chromedriver                        0x000000010f6ff2ad chromedriver + 4657837
12  chromedriver                        0x000000010f704130 chromedriver + 4677936
13  chromedriver                        0x000000010f70adef chromedriver + 4705775
14  chromedriver                        0x000000010f70505a chromedriver + 4681818
15  chromedriver                        0x000000010f6d792c chromedriver + 4495660
16  chromedriver                        0x000000010f722838 chromedriver + 4802616
17  chromedriver                        0x000000010f7229b7 chromedriver + 4802999
18  chromedriver                        0x000000010f73399f chromedriver + 4872607
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8185474e1 _pthread_start + 125
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff818542f6b thread_start + 15
```

Comment: this might help. nothing in your pasted code changes what chrome is used. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978464/chromedriver-custom-chrome-executable-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase to mix any Chrome browser version with any chromedriver version.

After `pip install seleniumbase`, you can run the following script with `python` to force a specific chromedriver version for the already-installed Chrome version:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="chrome", driver_version="114")
driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.quit()
```

Here's the output on the first run if you don't already have chromedriver 114 on your PATH:

```bash
Warning: chromedriver update needed. Getting it now:

*** chromedriver to download = 114.0.5735.90 (Legacy Version)

Downloading chromedriver_mac_arm64.zip from:
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/114.0.5735.90/chromedriver_mac_arm64.zip ...
Download Complete!

Extracting ['chromedriver'] from chromedriver_mac_arm64.zip ...
Unzip Complete!

The file [chromedriver] was saved to:
~/seleniumbase/drivers/chromedriver

Making [chromedriver 114.0.5735.90] executable ...
[chromedriver 114.0.5735.90] is now ready for use!
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of selenium you use. If you use version `4.11.0` or above, you can use the below code to launch [CFT version of chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-for-testing/). No need to download and set path of `chromedriver.exe` or `chrome.exe`, selenium will take care of all that.

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.browser_version = 114

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
url = "https://google.com"
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
website_source = driver.page_source
print(website_source)
```

**NOTE:** Selenium will download and use the Chrome for Testing version of chrome browser and not regular chrome browser. When you run the above code you will see the browser and its version as below:

[image]

[image]